# How to use an object with nullable fields in HttpParams?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

When writing an Angular REST client that uses query parameters from an object, the following code works as intended:

```
  search(params: {query: string, page: number, size: number}): Observable<any> {
    let p = new HttpParams({fromObject: params});
    return this.http.get('http://localhost', {params: p});
  }
```

However if I want to make any of the parameters optional using the `nullable?` syntax, that no longer works. The only way I've found is very verbose:

```
  search(params?: {query?: string, page?: number, size?: number}): Observable<any> {
    let p = new HttpParams();
    if (params) {
      if (params.query) {
        p = p.set('query', params.query);
      }
      if (params.page) {
        p = p.set('page', params.page);
      }
      if (params.size) {
        p = p.set('size', params.size);
      }
    }
    return this.http.get('http://localhost', {params: p});
  }
```

Is there a way to shorten this up, similar to the first example but still allowing for optional parameters?

Comment: Angular currently doesn't have any built-in mechanism to prevent undefined parameters from being included by `HttpParams`, however, there is an open issue to address this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20564

Answer (score 0):

in `es6` you can simple do it like this

```js
search(params: {query?: string, page?: number, size?: number} = {}): Observable<any> {
    const p = new HttpParams({fromObject: { ...params } });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost', {params: p});
}
```

see this [Default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Typescript returns ` Type '{ query?: string | undefined; page?: number | undefined; size?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [param: string]: string | readonly string[]; }'`

Comment: @Paul const p = new HttpParams({fromObject: { ...params });  should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the typescript `as` keyword. Something like this:

```
// Define the type outside of the class.
type ParamOptions = { [param: string]: string | readonly string[]; }




// now you can use the type
search(params: { query?: string; page?: number; size?: number } = {}): Observable<any> {
        const p = new HttpParams({ fromObject: params as ParamOptions});
        return this.http.get("http://localhost", { params: p });
}
```